# MongoDB Query Optimization with POST request

Tags: python, mongodb

What is the best way to query a mongo database using the results of a POST request that can return different permutations of variables?

For example, if I create the following python function to query the database I want to account for the possibility of a beach, date, or taxon **not being specified**, in which case I only need to query for the other parameters.

```
def query_mongo_collection(collection, beach, date, taxon):
db = setup_mongoclient(collection)

cursor = db.posts.find({'beach': beach}) **//possibly query for the other parameters as well**
```

Is this best accomplished with the logic outside of the mongo query, such as

```
if beach == 'Any':
    query_date_and_taxon()
if date == 'Any':
    query_beach_and_taxon()
if taxon == 'Any':
    query_beach_and_date()
```

...etc

This code is ugly and I was looking to see if there was any more elegant solution available.  Thanks so much!

Comment: will your data have values for any of those keys even if they are not specified by your POST request?

Comment: If they are not specified by the POST request then I want to query the database with only the variables which were specified, but yes there will be data for the keys which were not specified.

Comment: hmm yeah if the keys will still exist and have values and you want to be able to filter by any number of keys provided you'll have to do some of that work in python with the if statements. i mean it's probably possible in mongo but it gets pretty messy so i don't think it's worth it.